# Reading "runtime" section from external file in .NET configuration

Tags: c#, .net, configuration, web-config, app-config

I've read this article, and it seems that while `runtime` section of .NET configuration can be given an external file via `configSource` attribute, but it doesn't read the external configuration and ignores it.

http://world.episerver.com/blogs/Magnus-Rahl/Dates/2011/6/Todays-gotcha-configSource-on-the-runtime-section-element/

I'm stuck in a situation that I need to redirect binding of a lot of assmblies in a lot of projects, which is not hard per se, but really dirty from the point of maintenance.

How can I reuse binding redirects across multiple projects in .NET configuration?